# Is damage from Rotten Core rounded up or down?

Tags: dicey-dungeons

Using [Rotten Core](https://diceydungeons.fandom.com/wiki/Rotten_Core) reduces health by half. Is the health lost rounded up or down when dealing with odd numbers? For example, if I'm attacked with Rotten Core while at 15 HP, will I lose 7 HP or 8 HP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damage is rounded down when using Rotten Core. I used the Thief's ability to steal Rotten Core. When used on an enemy with 25 hp, the attack did 12 damage.